# How to start MATLAB via bash script in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with arguments and DISPLAY environment variable?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, display

On a single machine, I have a PHP script that uses exec to call a bash script, `AQuA_WBSv_Instance_Spool.sh,` as user 'matlab_executor' and does not wait for a return:

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid sudo -u matlab_executor bash /home/matlab_executor/matlab/AQUA_WBSv/AQuA_WBSv_Instance_Spool.sh testU > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

`AQuA_WBSv_Instance_Spool.sh`, located in `/home/matlab_executor/matlab/AQUA_WBSv/`, looks like the following:

```
#DISPLAY=:0 ./matlab -r 'AQuA_WBSv_Main("$1")'| tr -d '\r'
echo "spooler entry with argument $1 executing as user $(whoami)" > /home/matlab_executor/matlab/AQUA_WBSv/output.txt | tr -d '\r'
```

and it successfully writes to `output.txt` in the same directory with the following:

```
spooler entry with argument testU executing as user matlab_executor
```

Furthermore, while logged in as `matlab_executor` locally, running `DISPLAY=:0 ./matlab -r 'AQuA_WBSv_Main("testU")'` in a terminal, started in the same directory, allows MATLAB to start and successfully runs the function provided via the argument -r while showing visually on the screen.

My question is:

When I remove the hash from `#DISPLAY=:0 ./matlab -r 'AQuA_WBSv_Main("$1")'| tr -d '\r'` within the bash script, i.e. the script is now:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ./matlab -r 'AQuA_WBSv_Main("$1")'| tr -d '\r'
echo "spooler entry with argument $1 executing as user $(whoami)" > /home/matlab_executor/matlab/AQUA_WBSv/output.txt | tr -d '\r'
```

**why doesn't MATLAB start or show up visually while logged in locally and why do I get no output in output.txt?**

Thanks

Comment: Does the `matlab` process ever finish?

Comment: Ah no, it doesn't until I manually close it. Swapping the two lines in the bash script now results in me seeing the output in the text file, but MATLAB still does not start. I expect MATLAB to show up on the display when I am logged in as user matlab_executor locally.

Comment: You are piping an (most likely) empty output to `tr -d \r` in the last line - why, accidental duplication? Is the display you get when logged in as that user `:0`? btw, this seems very convoluted - could you describe your basic goal more generally?